# Installing Tensorflow 1.3 (No module named tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow

I am initializing a new VM with Ubuntu 17 on Google Cloud Platform, I then SSH into the newly created VM, upload this script and run it...

```
#! /bin/bash
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
sudo pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Now, this works for me, when I launch a Python interactive environment

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

does not throw an error, however, if I run the same script but replace

```
tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

with

```
tensorflow-1.3.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

I get:

```
ImportError: No module named tensorflow
```

... incredibly frustrating, especially since the contrib library doesn't seem to be apart of the 0.5 version... any ideas of what is going on, perhaps how I can first install 0.5 and then upgrade to 1.3 ?

Comment: Just to check -- are both installations part of the same Python? Based on your PIP seems like yes, but just double-checking. Python on GCP Ubuntu defaults to python 2.7, maybe your v1.3 gets installed into Python 3? You could try by using Python3 instead of Python?

Comment: Getting the URL from here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#python_27 but I suppose I can try updating python to 3 and use the other URL.  Will report what happens

Comment: After `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install python3.6`, I'm getting this error:

_tensorflow-1.3.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform._ ... btw, I'm creating an entirely new VM instance to test these configurations so there's no contamination from anything prior to the default OS...

Comment: Ok, I had to get a larger machine type, but first installing 0.5 and then doing `sudo pip install tensorflow --upgrade` and then
`sudo pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/protobuf-3.1.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl` works

Comment: No i think if you did 2.7 originally it should have been all OK. I haven't tried 1.3 yet, but with all prior versions it used to go very smoothly on GCP.

Comment: I've actually made a copy of the image as a custom image type which makes it super easy next time I create an instance since I can now just skip all of this and the image will already have an up and running version of Tensorflow.

Answer (score 1):

I also get the same then i tried `pip install tensorflow` after worked fine